# Pandas calculate net based on previous row value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe from which I am trying to get net value based on previous row values

| id | date | current_value | previous_date_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | -1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 |

I am trying to achieve,

| id | date | current_value | previous_date_value | net_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | -1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

eg: for row 1, 1 (current_value) + 2 (previous_date_value) = 3

for row 2, -1 (current_value) + 3 (net_value from previous row) = 2

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like:

```
df['net_value'] = (df.groupby(['id','date'])
                     ['current_value'].cumsum() 
                     .add(df['previous_date_value'])
```

)